# Map<classObject,List> is not formed as expected

Tags: java, json, jackson, lombok

I have the below json, which i need to read and construct as `Map<NamePlateOrder, List<Orders>>`

Sample json:

```
`{
   "orders":[
      {
         "order":[
            {
               "OrderReference":{
                  "reference":68203486,
                  "version":1
               }
            },
            {
               "OrderReference":{
                  "reference":68203487,
                  "version":1
               }
            }
         ],
         "nameplate":{
            "id":"98ZZ",
            "label":"VEC"            
         }
      }
   ]
}`
```

Below is the code:

```
 public class NamePlateOrder {

    public ArrayList<Orders> orders;


    @EqualsAndHashCode
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Builder
    public static class NameplateCatalogForOrder {
        public String id;
        public String label;
    }

    @EqualsAndHashCode
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Builder
    public static class Orders {
        public List<Order> order; //this should be stored as value.
        public NameplateCatalogForOrder nameplate; //this should be stored as key
    }

    @EqualsAndHashCode
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Builder
    public static class Order {
        @JsonProperty("OrderReference")
        public OrderReference orderReference;
    }

    @EqualsAndHashCode
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Builder
    public static class OrderReference {
        public int reference;
        public int version;
    }
}
```

Sample code tried to construct `Map<NameplateCatalogForOrder, List<Orders>>`

```
`NamePlateOrder models = om.readValue(sql2, NamePlateOrder.class);

System.out.println("NNamePlateWithOrder " + models);

Map<NamePlateOrder.NameplateCatalogForOrder, List<NamePlateOrder.Order>> nameplateListMap = new HashMap<>();

for(NamePlateOrder.Orders firstOrders : models.getOrders()){
    NamePlateOrder.NameplateCatalogForOrder n1 = firstOrders.getNameplate();
    List<NamePlateOrder.Order> ordersListForNamePlate = firstOrders.getOrder();
    nameplateListMap.put(n1, ordersListForNamePlate);

}`
```

But the output when executed the above code is not as expected. The key n1 is printing as object reference. The expected output should be same as the sample json which we are reading to construct the same.
Any inputs would be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by that *"The key n1 is printing as object reference."*. Can show what's exactly with the Map you've created?

Answer (score 2):

> ```java
> @EqualsAndHashCode
>    @AllArgsConstructor
>    @NoArgsConstructor
>    @Getter
>    @Setter
>    @Builder
>    public static class Order {
> ```

This christmas tree does not include `@ToString`, hence, the toString() implementation of these things would print something like `Order@12af9cc`, which I think is what you mean with 'prints its object reference'. In other words, your code is doing exactly what you asked it to.

I suggest you use `@Value @Builder` instead and ditch the setters. It's a bit odd to want a builder for a mutable class, after all (why not just invoke the setters instead?). If you must have them, `@NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor @Value @Data` works too. `@Data` combines `@EqualsAndHashCode @Getter @Setter @ToString` which is what you want.